# Android Layouts: Moving Items

Tags: android, user-interface, element, alignment

I was wondering how one might align two or more UI elements to the bottom of a screen instead of them just stacking as they normally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/myBottomLayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     <View
         android:id="@+id/leftItem"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content">
     <View
         android:id="@+id/rightItem"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="id/leftItem">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But I would like other things aligned to the top.  Can I do that with this XML?

Comment: definitely, I forgot to mention that this code assumes the parent element is a RelativeLayout as well. To align to the top, make the other elements align to the top. This will work if the parent element is a RelativeLayout.